# R neuralnet taking huge number of steps for linear function f(x)=19x

Tags: r, neural-network, convergence

So here is the scenario:-

I ran the following code which creates neural network (uses neuralnet package in R) to approximate the function f(x)=x^2:-

```
set.seed(2016);
rm(list=ls());
# Prepare Training Data
attribute<-as.data.frame(sample(seq(-2,2,length=50), 50 , replace=FALSE ),ncol=1);
response<-attribute^2;
data <- cbind(attribute,response);
colnames(data)<- c("attribute","response");

# Create DNN
fit<-neuralnet(response~attribute,data=data,hidden = c(3,3),threshold=0.01);
fit$result.matrix;
```

This worked fine and converged in 3191 steps. Now I made a small change to the code -- I change the function being approximated. Instead of a quadratic function I used a very simple linear function `f(x)=2x`. This worked fine too, then I tweaked the coefficient of x and conducted multiple runs e.g.

```
f(x) = 2x
f(x) = 3x
.
.
f(x) = 19x
```

Up to this point it worked fine. But one thing I noticed is that number of steps required to converged were dramatically increasing from 2x to 19x. The number of steps for 19x for example are astonishing **84099**. This is weird that the DNN is taking so many steps to converge only for a linear function whereas for the quadratic function f(x)=x^2 it only took 3191 steps.

So when I changed the function to f(x)=20x , it probably needs more steps and so I got the following warning:-

```
> set.seed(2016);
> rm(list=ls());
> # Prepare Training Data
> attribute<-as.data.frame(sample(seq(-2,2,length=50), 50 , replace=FALSE ),ncol=1);
> response<-attribute*20;
> data <- cbind(attribute,response);
> colnames(data)<- c("attribute","response");
> 
> # Create DNN
> fit<-neuralnet(response~attribute,data=data,hidden = c(3,3),threshold=0.01);
Warning message:
algorithm did not converge in 1 of 1 repetition(s) within the stepmax 
> fit$result.matrix;
```

So I guess I can tweak the default stepmax parameter and increase the steps. But the real question is -- why should it need so many steps just for a simple linear function like this?

Comment: Interesting result -- changing number of nodes in hidden layers from 3 to 10 reduced number of steps dramatically for the function f(x)=19x -- from 84099 steps to now 1634 steps:-   fit<-neuralnet(response~attribute,data=data,hidden = c(3,10),threshold=0.01)

Comment: After experimenting with both number of hidden layers and number of nodes in hidden layer the optimal combination for this functon turned out to be hidden = c(8,10) , number of steps now 698

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest thing here, I believe, is that you need to scale your data.  As you values get larger the neural network needs to cover a larger range of results (this can be dealt with using more sophisticated techniques like different forms of `momentum` but that isn't the point here).  If you simply scale your data like so:

```
maxs <- apply(data, 2, max) 
mins <- apply(data, 2, min)

raw.sc <- scale(data, center = mins, scale = maxs - mins)
scaled <- as.data.frame(raw.sc)
```

You can now create a NN much more quickly.  Note - you shouldn't need multiple layers for a linear function.  Here I demonstrate this with a single layer, one node network.  This isn't really a problem for 'deep learning'.

```
set.seed(123)
# Create NN
fit<-neuralnet(response~attribute,data=scaled,hidden = c(1),threshold=0.01);


# make sure to use normalized input and de-normalize the output
pr.nn <- compute(fit, scaled$attribute)
pr.nn_ <- pr.nn$net.result*attr(raw.sc, 'scaled:scale')[2] + attr(raw.sc, 'scaled:center')[2]
```

In this case, it converges in 1349 steps.  You then calculate some metric like MSE.

```
# MSE
sum((data$response - pr.nn_)^2)/nrow(data)
```

Comment: I know this is not a candidate for deep learning -- I was just trying to tweak few things and try to learn. Thanks